# Show a validation message in "then" instead of closing the Swal automatically

Tags: sweetalert2

Is it possible to have a Sweetalert *(2)* not close in the `then` method after a `preConfirm` fetch? If the request returns something specific, I'd like to simply keep the Swal open, but do a `Swal.showValidationMessage()` rather than opening an entire new alert. When doing the validation message in the `then` method, it's shown for a split-second, but the alert closes automatically.

Is there a way to keep the alert open?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you should be calling the `Swal.showValidationMessage()` function inside the `preConfirm()` option, not in the `then()` promise return.

Would validating whatever input you're looking for inside the `preConfirm()` just work fine?

Example:

```js
Swal.fire({
    title: "title",
    text: "text",
    icon: "info",
    showCancelButton: true,
    cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
    confirmButtonText: "Done!",
    html: `<input id="input1 class="swal2-input" />
           <input id="input2 class="swal2-input" />`,
    preConfirm: () => {
        let value1 = Swal.getPopup().querySelector('#input1').value;
        let value2 = Swal.getPopup().querySelector('#input2').value;

        if (value1 == somethingWrong1) {
            // Notify error and keep alert open.
            Swal.showValidationMessage('Invalid input #1.');

        } else if (value2 == somethingWrong2) {
            // Notify error and keep alert open.
            Swal.showValidationMessage('Invalid input #2.');

        } else {
            // Promise return value that will be available inside the 'then()'.
            // Alert will now close.
            return {
                input1: input1,
                input2: input2
            };
        }
    }
}).then((inputs) => {
    if (inputs !== "cancel") {
        // Access the inputs using: inputs.value.input1 and inputs.value.input2
        // And do whatever you want.
    }
});
```

Comment: The issue is that I need to validate the return from a request, and I can't seem to access the returned data in preConfirm - only the "then" method

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example:

```
Swal.fire({
title: "title",
text: "text",
icon: "info",
showCancelButton: true,
cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
confirmButtonText: "Done!",
html: "<input id="input1 class="swal2-input" />
       <input id="input2 class="swal2-input" />",
preConfirm: () => {
    let value1 = Swal.getPopup().querySelector('#input1').value;
    let value2 = Swal.getPopup().querySelector('#input2').value;

    if (value1 == somethingWrong1) {
        // Notify error and keep alert open.
        Swal.showValidationMessage("Invalid input #1.");
       // Set a return here to prevent any further progress
       return;

    } else if (value2 == somethingWrong2) {
        // Notify error and keep alert open.
        Swal.showValidationMessage('Invalid input #2.'); 
         // Set a return here to prevent any further progress
          return;

    } else {

                   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

                    //DO whatever you need to do with your variables, ajax etc
                  input1,input2
                   //resolve(); when success
                   //reject(); when error

                });
         }
    }
    });
```